# ¿Cómo agregar una columna adicional con valores específicos a una consulta SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL

```
 SELECT top 2 nom_vacante  FROM vacantes ORDER BY fecha_captura DESC
```

El resultado que me da es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero realizar es agregar otra columna llamada img y que siempre en el primer registro en la nueva columna aparezca el img1 y en el segundo img2. Cabe aclarar que los valores de la columna nom_vacante puede cambiar.

¿Es posible realizar esta operación? No tengo idea de como hacer esto. Me podrían apoyar, gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Es posible si. Pero deberías de mejorar un montón la pregunta. Leer [ask]. Posible solución [Row_number en mySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: ¿Es posible que ese SQL sea de Access?

Comment: ¿Y de que depende que en un caso sea img1 y en el otro img2? ¿Qué es img1 e img2?